# ggplot2 use column values as legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

How can I use some custom values from a column as legend? I currently do

```
library(ggplot2)

test <- data.frame(condition = as.factor(c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C")),
                       value = c(4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 1, 0),
                       color = as.factor(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2)))
ggplot(
    test,
    aes(x=condition, y=value, color=color)
) +
    geom_boxplot()
```

Which gives me:

[image]

But I want the legend to contain 3 items, one for each condition (with custom labels and of course the correct color). I haven't managed to do this. Even in the simpler case without color:

```
ggplot(test, aes(x=condition, y=value)) + geom_boxplot()
```

I'll get an image with no legend, and I really don't know how to add one that uses that specific column as data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(ggplot2)

test <- data.frame(condition = as.factor(c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C")),
                   value = c(4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 1, 0),
                   color = as.factor(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2)))
ggplot(
  test,
  aes(x=condition, y=value, color=interaction(condition,color))
) +
  geom_boxplot()+
  scale_color_manual(values=c('tomato','tomato','cyan'),
                     labels=c('1','1','2'))+
  labs(color='color')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This isn't giving me the correct colors. As per the `color` column of my data frame, I want A and B to have the same color.

Comment: @piegames Hi, I have updated the code for you. Hope that helps you!

Comment: Yes it does, thank you! I also managed to plug in a color palette by using `values=brewer.pal(3, "Dark2")[c(1, 1, 2)]`

Comment: @piegames Great! If this answer in any sense helped you consider potentially accepting it. Kind regards and many thanks!

Comment: I planned to do that, but I thought I was still on the "new question timer".